# How to create a program that converts from Euro to Peso and vice versa?

Tags: c#

In console application, if the value of 1 Euro is equal to 17 Peso, then how would I create a program that converts from Euro to Peso and vice versa? I would like to have a function named convertEuroPeso.

I would like to enter one number (let's say 5) into the program and the program would assume in one line that 5 is a Euro and convert it to Peso. At the same time, on a second line, the program would assume that 5 is a Peso and convert it to a Euro.

Comment: Sounds like a first-year college assignment. What have you tried? Can you show code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double value, peso, euro;
        Console.Write("Enter the value: ");

        value = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("The value is = {0} peso", peso = ValueToPeso(value));
        Console.WriteLine("The value is = {0} euro", (euro = ValueToEuro(value)).ToString("f2"));
    }

    // convert value to Peso
    public static double ValueToPeso(double value)
    {
        return value * 17;
    }

    // convert value to Euro 
    public static double ValueToEuro(double value)
    {
        return value / 17;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Computers are excellent with math.

```
void convertEuroPeso(double value)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Euro's equals {1} Peso's", value, value * 17));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Peso's equals {1} Euro's", value, value / 17));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be very tricky. Since you have provided no code I will give you some pseudocode you might find useful:

```
-declare convertEuroToPeso constant (use a double for currency)
-declare convertPesoToEuro constant (use a double for currency)
-read in a number from a user and save it to a variable convertMe
-multiply convertMe * convertEuroToPeso and print the result to the user
-multiply convertMe * convertPesoToEuro and print the result to the user
```

If you are finding it tough, then post your attempt at a solution and we can provide further help from there.

**Update: Anyone posting code solutions to this problem won't be helping. This looks to me like a homework question, and he/she should give it a go themselves if they wish to learn anything**

Answer (score 0):

Create one public flag variable for alternatively converting from/to currency like

```
public bool flag;
```

and Create method like this

```
double ConvertCurrency(double input)
{
 if(flag)
 {
  return input*17;
  flag=false;
 }

else
 {
  return input/17;
  flag=true;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like DaveDev said, it's kinda weird to ask this simple question without any code.
Anyway, here is 2 simple fonction to do what you are asking.

```
public static Decimal convertPesoEuro(Decimal Peso)
{
     return Peso / 17.0;
}
public static Decimal convertEuroPeso(Decimal Euro)
{
     return Euro * 17.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a few pointers:

- For write on console use `Console.WriteLine("message")`
- For reading input use `var inputText = Console.ReadLine();`
- For parsing use `var inputValue = Double.Parse(inputText)`

Put a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the program so it doesn't close automatically

As far as the algorithm is quite simple is only a multiplication by the conversion factor